# Using Pipenv with Pydev

Tags: pydev

I am attempting to use `Pipenv` with `Pydev` and I am encountering a problem. If you use `Pipenv` standalone, you can use the environment variable `WORKON_HOME` to specify where the virtual environment should be created. It does not appear possible to do this in a `Pydev` environment and I am at a loss to know how to proceed. I am running `Eclipse` and `Pydev` under `Windows 10`

Comment: If you set that environment variable (`WORKON_HOME`) and launch Eclipse with that environment variable set, doesn't it work?